# How to disable HUD transparency in Half-Life?

Tags: half-life

The UI doesn't scale based on resolution and HUD is relatively diminished especially in 4K, the crosshair in particular is difficult to see with weapons using a more complex pattern.

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

[image: screen3]

Having  a non-transparent HUD would help playing at high resolutions. How can I disable HUD transparency?

Comment: The crosshair is pointed at the top of the ladder (use the rocket launcher's laser pointer as a reference). Gamma seems affected when capturing fullscreen applications, the image is brighter in-game. I had to scale the images to 1920x1080 since all were over the  stack.imgur.com 2MB limit at 4K; the transparency may be more difficult to spot due the host's JPG compression.

Comment: A better solution would likely be simply increasing the UI scale, any transparency would be much less of an issue (and the original HUD appearance may be preferred by many).

Comment: As mentioned in the answer comments, the crosshair seemingly has no transparency after all (I ran the game at 640 x 480 and compared with the other HUD elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried changing some parameters in the console, but none of the known commands improved the HUD visibility. With *hud_draw 1* the HUD is in all probability at maximum opacity.

This leads me to to believe the transparency of the entire HUD - including the in-game text messages - is hard-coded. To change it, [you would have to recompile the applicable scripts](https://www.moddb.com/games/half-life/tutorials/hud-colouring).

**What you can do for increased effectiveness, is change the sprites that are used**. 
These can be found in the 'half-life/valve/sprites' folder, and the file with the crosshairs is appropriately named *crosshairs.spr*.
You can use a number of small programs to open these files, and convert them to workable file formats. I've used [*Sprite Explorer*](https://gamebanana.com/tools/download/4775).

Naturally, there are edited versions available already, and [**these ones**](https://forums.svencoop.com/showthread.php/38005-Bigger-Crosshairs), made by *w00tguy123* on the SvenCoop forum, might help you out.

Comment: @user598527 This is likely not a concern anymore, but have you tried this?

Comment: Sorry for not responding initially. I somehow managed not to test your solutions, the Sven co-op forum appears not to be online anymore and https://archive.org/web/ doesn't have the page archived. I'll see if converting the sprites is viable on Linux (I haven't had Windows installed in a while).

Comment: The crosshair seemingly has no transparency after all — I ran the game at 640 x 480 and compared with the other HUD elements.