# How can I make the UI bigger in Half Life 1?

Tags: half-life

I started playing Half Life 1 on 1366x768, and I feel that every user interface item is too small (weapon selector, ammo, health & HEV suit energy, pause menu and others).

How can I make the UI in Half-Life 1 (or any GoldSrc game) bigger?

Comment: "how to increase the UI scale / scaling" would be a more appropriate title, in formal sense?

Comment: @user598527 Yeah, but it will be harder to find by regular people that don't know what "scaling" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the [25th Anniversary Update](https://www.half-life.com/en/halflife25/) released on [November 17, 2023](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/70/view/6941797379568863069), Half-Life's HUD will now scale based on your screen resolution.

[image: HUD before]

[image: HUD after]

Answer (score 3):

**The only thing you can do is change the HUD sprites**.

In the folder '*steam\steamapps\common\half-life\valve\sprites*' you can find both the *.spr* files that contain the graphics, and *.txt* files that are used to tell the game how to use these 'spritesheets'.
By increasing the size of the HUD graphics and editing the *.txt* files to correspond with those changes, you can adjust the HUD to your liking.

You can open the *.spr* files with [SprView](http://hacks-cs.clan.su/load/programs_for_cs_1_6/sprite_tools/sprview/95-1-0-200), export them as *.bmp* files, edit them in your favourite image editing program (your least favourite will also do), and import them into [Sprite Wizard](http://www.slackiller.com/hlprograms.htm) to convert them back to *.spr* files.
Make sure that the graphic files are saved in 256 colours and have dimensions that are a power of two (up to 256 px, which doesn't give a lot of room for enlargement). Sprite Wizard will warn you otherwise.
You'll want to change the *640hud#.spr* files (the *320hud#.spr* files are for screen width resolutions lower than 640 px), containing all the weapon graphics, and *crosshairs.spr*, containing all the ..crosshairs.

Now to the more tedious task of tackling the changed coordinates.

The *.txt* files are called *hud.txt* and *weapon_[x].txt*, and contain the coordinates of all the HUD elements, listed as strings like the following:

`number_0       640  640hud7    0   0   20  24`

`number_0` is the icon to be displayed.

> `640`: all resolutions of 640x480 or above will use these directions. Lower resolutions use the 320 instructions.
>   `640hud7`: the name of the sprite that is to be used
>   `0`: X-coordinate on the sprite where the game image should begin
>   `0`: Y-coordinate on the sprite where the game image should begin
>   `20`: Width of the sprite that should be used, in pixels
>   `24`: Height of the sprite that should be used, in pixels <sup>([source](https://www.quaddicted.com/webarchive/www.planetfortress.com/tfc/mod/sprites.shtml))</sup>

If, for example, you just scaled the images to twice their size, you can just multiply all numbers by 2.

As proof, I changed the crosshair sprite and the coordinates of the 9mm handgun from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I also created a new and larger icon for the crowbar, while I was getting acquainted with the process (the second image shows a comparison between the enlarged icon for the Beretta 92FS (with the original sized selection brackets) and the original icon for the Colt Python):

[image]

This will work for all Goldsource games (except, of course, that the folder paths will differ slightly).

---

See also [this related answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/341989/222022).

Comment: Didn't smaller resolution also make everything bigger ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев What do you mean? That the HUD would scale to the resolution? In that case, no, it doesn't. Half-Life (and other Goldsource games) only have spritesheets for two groups of resolutions: everything up to 640, and everything from 640 onward.

Comment: I haven't tried it recently but they used to change with changing resolution.

Comment: This HUD replacement https://gamebanana.com/mods/download/24741 worked well enough at 3840 × 2160 (the '4K' version) — you may want to verify and update your question.  The crosshair appears to have no transparency in the original game.